# Deep learning-based approach VS deep learning approach

Tags: hyphenation, compound-words

I would like to find an expression to describe the approaches that use deep learning to solve a computer-related task and then compare them to the traditional approaches i.e., the approaches that do not use deep learning to solve the same task.

At first, I called the approaches that use deep learning, *the deep learning-based approaches*. But, I googled and I saw that the expression *the deep learing approaches* also exists. I am not sure what is the difference between *the deep learning-based approach* and *the deep learning approach*. Is there a semantic difference between them? Personally, I would prefer to use *the deep learning approach* beacuse it is shorter, but I am not sure if it means the same as *the deep learning-based approach*.

Comment: What is the full sentence in which you plan to use the phrase?

Comment: "deep learning-based approach" looks like "deep" is modifying "learning-based", rather than referring to the concept of "deep learning".

Comment: "deep learning" has become a set phrase, so use that.